# calling a function with passing parameters to a function, and from a function to a procedure

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

There is a function that accepts a string array as input. The function calls a stored procedure that filters data by column based on the string array from the function and returns the cursor.
How to pass an array of strings to a function call correctly?

Now it looks like this

```
create function pricing.report_avg_price_ref(arr_string text[]) returns refcursor
       language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
ret_cursor refcursor;
begin
open ret_cursor for
select rap.id,
       rap.region_name,
       rap.fc_code,
       rap.fc_name,
       rap.ph3_code,
       rap.ph3_name,
       rap.ph4_code,
       rap.ph4_name,
       rap.product_plu,
       rap.product_name,
       rap.price_value
from pricing.report_avg_price rap
where rap.region_name = any (arr_string);
return ret_cursor;
end;
$$
```

So it is called

```
List<String> regionNames = List.of('London', 'Paris');
Query<ReportAveragePrice> query = statelessSession.createNamedQuery(REPORT_REF_QUERY_NAME, ReportAveragePrice.class);
query.setParameter(1,  regionNames);
```

Description in entity

```
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = ReportAveragePrice.REPORT_REF_QUERY_NAME,
        query = "{ ? = call pricing.report_avg_price_ref(?) }",
        callable = true,
        cacheMode = CacheModeType.IGNORE,
        resultClass = ReportAveragePrice.class
    )
```

This is how the call works if the function and procedure looks like :

```
create function pricing.report_avg_price_ref() returns refcursor
       language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
ret_cursor refcursor;
begin
open ret_cursor for
select rap.id,
       rap.region_name,
       rap.fc_code,
       rap.fc_name,
       rap.ph3_code,
       rap.ph3_name,
       rap.ph4_code,
       rap.ph4_name,
       rap.product_plu,
       rap.product_name,
       rap.price_value
from pricing.report_avg_price rap
where rap.region_name = any array (['London']);
return ret_cursor;
end;
$$
```

Then all entries are output, where region_name = 'London'

No how to call the list of translations = List.of('London', 'Paris')?